# adjustPan combined with EditText inputType="textPassword" covers a portion of the EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

As the title suggests, when I add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my Manifest, as well as `inputType="textPassword"` in my password `EditText`, the `adjustPan` still covers a portion of the `editText`. For reference, here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".home.LoginActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/log_in_launcher_icon"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_logo" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/log_in_rellay1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_launcher_icon"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/log_in_linlay1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="@string/email_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/log_in_et_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/log_in_et_password"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="@string/password_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/log_in_et_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/log_in_pb"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_linlay1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/log_in_btn_log_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_linlay1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:paddingEnd="70dp"
                android:paddingStart="70dp"
                android:text="@string/log_in_title"
                android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/log_in_rellay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_in_btn_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="@string/log_in_sign_up"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_in_btn_forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="@string/log_in_forgot_password"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd highly appreciate if somebody could help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of soft keyboard. It's just responsible for text part of `EditText` not other part of view.

Here is a code snippet I wrote before It helps you to scroll up your view in you custom height.

```
  final View root  = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    {
        root.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    }
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r2 = new Rect();
        root.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r2);
        int keyboardHeight = r.height() - r2.height();
        if (keyboardHeight > 100) {
            root.scrollTo(0, keyboardHeight);
        }
        else {
            root.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

`root.scrollTo(0, keyboardHeight);` in this line you can change `0` and `keyboardHeight` to your custom values.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, mate! I'll be sure to experiment with this and resolve the problem!

Comment: Anytime :), if it solved your problem please accept answer and vote up.

Comment: I voted up but my reputation is too low for it to be shown :/